# Drag and resize image and put this image over another and merge in PHP

Tags: php, image, merge, resize, drag

I want to merge 3 images using PHP. I want to drag 2 images to top of the other image dynamic positions and merge these 3 images into one single image.
can anybody pls tell how can I do that?

Comment: Split your task into smaller ones and solve them iteratively, one by one.

Comment: Show some code first! Also, you say "drag", do you mean have the user drag and drop it (with javascript), then have PHP combine them?

Comment: PHP has no 'display' on which you can drag/drop. You'll need something else, like javascript in a browser, to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand your question clearly but to merge images with php i'm using GD library. You can find more information about this here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Here is an example for merge 2 pictures to one: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php

To drag(like drag&drop), you can use javascript.

Comment: ok now its ok  Now I want to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560746/how-to-get-new-position-after-transform-div-jquery can you help me to do that ??